# Monitoring for mount volume in docker stack

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, docker-volume

I am deploying a service using docker stack (in docker swarm cluster). My docker-compose.yml has some volumes mapped like this,

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  awcm:
    image: test
    hostname: '{{.Node.Hostname}}'
    deploy:
      mode: global
    volumes:
      - type: volume
        source: nfsshare
        target: /config
        volume:
          nocopy: true
      - "/var/logs:/logs"
volumes:
  nfsshare:
    driver_opts:
      type: "nfs"
      o: "addr=ip,nolock,soft,rw"
      device: ":/config/"
```

For swarm monitoring I am using setup https://github.com/stefanprodan/swarmprom

I would like to monitor the mapped volumes as well, specially nfs mount. Any suggestions on how to achieve that?